# what do end parenthesis() and semicolon ;

Tags: javascript

in the create object method **like** this Code:

```
var tiny.show=function(){  

}();
```

what do end parenthesis() and semicolon ;

Answer (score 5):

The parenthesis invoke the function and that function's returned value is assigned to `tiny.show` (which doesn't make sense to use a `var` there).

Answer (score 3):

The `;` is an optional end of statement marker in Javascript. If you skip it, the interpreter considers the end of line as the end of statement marker. However, using a `;` to delimit statements is considered to improve readability by many.

The initial `()` denotes that you are about to define an anonymous function and assign it to `tiny.show`. The final `()` marks and invocation i.e. function call.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common programming idiom in JavaScript used to implement to module pattern as well as the object factory pattern. You can kind of think of it as a way to create a sort of private scope in JavaScript

Here are some good reads on the topic:

- http://howtonode.org/object-graphs
- http://howtonode.org/object-graphs-2